# Borders in CSS drop-down menu not hidden & borders overlap

Tags: html, css, sass

[image: like this]

Here is a demo you can see in practice: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/p34x2b5d/12/)

---

### What I tried

```
/* Child menu */
nav ul ul {
  border: 0;   /* Add */

/* Child menu display with hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul > li {
  border: solid 1px #000;   /* Add */
}

/* ▼ Add */
nav ul li:hover > ul > li:last-child {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/2L6qgvr7/5/)
[image: like this]

However like this, border has been inserted into each child / grandchild menu & `border-top` of grandchild menu has ended up disappeared too.

I want to make only the outline border as a child / grandchild menu like `nav`. Is that possible?

I tried `border: initial;` or `border-top: initial;` etc, but it didn't work because the border disappeared..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you aren't actually hiding the child menus (and displaying them on hover), so their borders are displaying.

I played around with your jsfiddle -- I just tweaked `nav ul ul` to include `visibility: hidden;`, and `nav ul li:hover > ul` to include `visibility: visible;`. This makes your child menus `hidden` initially, and on hover, they become `visible`.

Here are the elements I changed:

```
/* Child menu */
nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  li {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: white;
    > a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 2rem;
    }
  }
}

/* Child menu display with hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  > li{
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! Thank you. The border is clear. How can I also clear the border of grandchild menu? [now status(image)](https://i.imgur.com/YkLnmtM.png)

Comment: @POP I was able to fix the appearance of a heaver border-top on the grandchild menu by adding `top: -1px;` to `nav ul ul ul`. Since both the main nav and the grandchild menu have a 1px border, the grandchild menu has the appearance of a 2px border-top. Moving the grandchild menu up 1px fixes that.

Comment: Oh I see! It worked well.
The small problem of the child menu "▼" disappearing was also solved by adding `visibility: visible;` to `ul::before` of `nav ul ul li`. [Finally this happened](https://i.imgur.com/K9fYAVH.png)
Thank you very much! xD

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the border attribute from your

```
   nav{
   [...]
       ul{
       [...]
            border: 1px solid black;
       }
   }
```

and add

```
    nav >ul > li,
    ul > li:hover > ul > li,
    ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover ul > li{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

at the end of your css.

Comment: Certainly the border before the hover has disappeared, but it was different from what I thought a little.. [This happens](https://i.imgur.com/ltkJNT6.png) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little closer to what you are looking for by replacing borders on the `<li>` with `box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;`.

Comment: There is no border in the child / grandchild menu, but this style has also felt good. [This happens](https://i.imgur.com/SsUenFZ.png) Thank you.